# Foreach loop gives length longer than length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a moment.

```
                var files = document.getElementById("filePostInput").files;
            LogData("files length " + files.length); // 1
            var formData = new FormData();
            
            for (var file in files)
            {
                formData.append("file",files[file].data,files[file].name);
                LogData("file name" + files[file].name);
            }
```

The Output:

> Thu, 26 Apr 2018 09:39:47 GMT: file nameitem
>
> Thu, 26 Apr 2018 09:39:47 GMT: file nameundefined
>
> Thu, 26 Apr 2018 09:39:47 GMT: file nameTest.txt
>
> Thu, 26 Apr 2018 09:39:47 GMT: files length 1

When I call files.length, I get 1. My foreach loop however, logs 3 file name's. The first is the name of the file I put into my file input, and the next two I have no idea what they are.

Could someone explain to me what is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: i don't see any forEach loop in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for (var file of files)` instead of `for (var file in files)`. A `for .. in` loop iterates over all the properties of `files`; a `for .. of` loop iterates over the items in the collection. This way you don't need the `[]` notation either:

```
for (var file of files)
{
    formData.append("file", file.data , file.name);
    LogData("file name" + file.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to be doing something silly. C# Habits. I can't accept your answer for nine minutes for some reason but i'll be back :)